# How can I set curve tilt in curve sculpt mode?

Tags: geometry-nodes, workflow

I've been updating my stylized hair workflow from using individual NURBS curves, to using the new hair sculpting features. One feature I was not able to find is the ability to change the tilt of curves. I know you can set the curve tilt of all curves at once through geometry nodes, but it would be nice to be able to set it on a per-curve basis. using weight painting on the parent mesh doesn't offer enough precision for this.

Comment: RMB/Curve Context Menu/Tilt (Ctrl+T)
or (N)/Tilt: [...] ?